# Vuejs v-model bind on blur to axios param

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to pass input to axios param.
console.log(country_id) returns country_id on blur correctly,
axios country_id param is not populated,
what am I missing

```
<div id="app">

        <input v-model="country_id" v-on:blur="addCountryId" />
        <ul>

            <li v-for="uploaded_segment in uploaded_segments"> @{{ uploaded_segment.name }}</li>
        </ul>
</div>

<script>
    new Vue({

    el: '#app',

    data: {

        uploaded_segments: [],
        country_id :''
    },
    methods: {

        addCountryId(){

     country_id= this.country_id;
     console.log(country_id);

}
},
    mounted() {

 axios.get('/get_segments', {
        params: {
            country_id: this.country_id
        }
    }) .then(response => this.uploaded_segments = response.data);

}
});
```

Comment: You are trying to pass input to axios param in the mountd() hook which is called only once after the instance has just been mounted. The initial value of country_id is ' '. Mounted hook does not look for changes , so it does not know user has inputed a country-id in the input field to fire axios again. Its better you write the axios request in the on:blur methos you have declared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user7814783 explained in a comment to your OP, the mounted hook is run only once after rendering - at this point, `country_id` is still empty (``).

You probably rather want to to use a watch function:

```
watch: {
  country_id(newlValue) {
    axios.get('/get_segments', {
        params: {
            country_id: this.country_id
        }
    }) .then(response => this.uploaded_segments = response.data);
  }
}
```

Since this would fire the request everytime the user changers even 1 character, consider using the lazy flag (`v-model.lazy="country_id"`) or debounce the watcher function (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#debounce-search-demo)

edit: Answering follow-up from the commments:

> how can I process multiple params that change on the watch function, the idea is to have multiple selects that filter the segments : paste.laravel.io/8NZeq

Move the functionality into a method, add a wathcer for every piece of data you want to watch, call that method from each

```
watch: {
  country_id: 'updateSegments',
  // short for: country_id: function() {  this.updateSegments() }
  brand_id: 'updateSegments',
},
methods: {
  updateSegments() {
        axios.get('/get_segments', {
            params: {
                country_id: this.country_id,
                brand_id: this.brand_id
            }
        }) .then(response => this.uploaded_segments = response.data);
      }
}
```

Comment: that really helped, how can I process multiple params that change on the watch function, the idea is to have multiple selects that filter the segments : https://paste.laravel.io/8NZeq

Comment: see my updated answer. Please accept it if it solves your orginial problem, thanks :)